# What does kwargs={'pk': self.pk} do in get_absolute_url method?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've finished a Django tutorial a few days ago and I've started to recap the functionalities in my application. In my models.py I've stumbled upon a method and the **kwargs** thing it's not that clearly to me. What is the logic behind this, can you explain to me what it does?
Thank you.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Creation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='creation_posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

What does **kwargs={'pk':self.pk})** do exactly? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When the `get_absolute_url` method is called upon it returns a reverse link to the URL at `blog:detail` and this will pass additional arguments to the URL, in this case being `pk`.

This will have been setup in the `urls.py` to something like the following.

`path('blog/detail/<pk>', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="blog_detail")`

Answer (score 1):

Same as url tag when passing arguments. That is,

```
{% url 'detail' pk = self.pk%}
```

is equivalent to

```
return reverse ('blog: detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.pk})
```

It's just building a link based on the path name and if your path has url parameters, then based on them. Because if you have such a path (for example): `path ('list / <int: post_id>', name = 'detail')`. You cannot just take and write in the link `{% url 'detail'%}`, as there can be dozens or hundreds of such pages. And for this, arguments are passed, in this case the arguments id `(model field) = cycle.id` (id of each post in the cycle) will be passed. `kwargs = {'pk': self.pk}`) - this will build a link based on the path name - detail and arguments. Here it will be like this: pk-url-parameter will be equal to pk of each instance of the model class.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Based on [kwarg documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

> **kwargs allows you to handle named arguments that you have not defined in advance.
>
> In a function call, keyword arguments must follow positional
> arguments.
>
> All the keyword arguments passed must match one of the arguments
> accepted by the function (e.g. actor is not a valid argument for the
> parrot function), and their order is not important.

But in your case, `kwargs` pass `pk` variable to your `blog:detail` URL and you can use this value in your view